# Which texts mention Patanjali other than Yoga Sutras? Which scriptures mention that Patanjali is an incarnation of Shesha?

Tags: avatars, patanjali

Do texts besides Yoga Sutras mention Patanjali? In which Shruti and Smriti text Patanjali is mentioned as an incarnation of Shesha?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mah%C4%81bh%C4%81%E1%B9%A3ya#Story_behind_Mahabhashya